# These two equations differ by one condition, why can one find a solution while the other cannot?

Tags: equation-solving

These two equations differ by one condition

```
a^2 == b^2 + c^2
```

```
In[11]:= 
Solve[{x0^2/a^2 + y0^2/b^2 == 1, a > b, 
   a > c, {a, b, c} > 0, {x0 - c, y0} . {x0 + c, y0} == 0}, {x0, y0}, 
  Reals] // FullSimplify

Out[11]= {{x0 -> 
   ConditionalExpression[-a Sqrt[(-b^2 + c^2)/(a^2 - b^2)], 
    0 < b < c && a > c], 
  y0 -> ConditionalExpression[-b Sqrt[(a^2 - c^2)/(a^2 - b^2)], 
    0 < b < c && a > c]}, {x0 -> 
   ConditionalExpression[-a Sqrt[(-b^2 + c^2)/(a^2 - b^2)], 
    0 < b < c && a > c], 
  y0 -> ConditionalExpression[b Sqrt[(a^2 - c^2)/(a^2 - b^2)], 
    0 < b < c && a > c]}, {x0 -> 
   ConditionalExpression[a Sqrt[(-b^2 + c^2)/(a^2 - b^2)], 
    0 < b < c && a > c], 
  y0 -> ConditionalExpression[-b Sqrt[(a^2 - c^2)/(a^2 - b^2)], 
    0 < b < c && a > c]}, {x0 -> 
   ConditionalExpression[a Sqrt[(-b^2 + c^2)/(a^2 - b^2)], 
    0 < b < c && a > c], 
  y0 -> ConditionalExpression[b Sqrt[(a^2 - c^2)/(a^2 - b^2)], 
    0 < b < c && a > c]}}
```

````
In[12]:= 
Solve[{x0^2/a^2 + y0^2/b^2 == 1, a^2 == b^2 + c^2, a > b, 
   a > c, {a, b, c} > 0, {x0 - c, y0} . {x0 + c, y0} == 0}, {x0, y0}, 
  Reals] // FullSimplify

Out[12]= {}
```
````

Comment: `Reduce[{x0^2/a^2 + y0^2/b^2 == 1, a^2 == b^2 + c^2, a > b, 
  a > c, {a, b, c} > 0, {x0 - c, y0} . {x0 + c, y0} == 0}, {x0, 
  y0}, Reals]`

Comment: The y0 obtained using this method has a flaw. The solution of y0 contains x0,```Sqrt[c^2 - x0^2] == y0``` and the solutions of x0 and y0 can only be represented by a, b, and c

Comment: The second imposes a nongeneric condition. I cannot test it right now, but it should work if you add either of a or b to the set of variables to solve for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

You have added an equation. With three equations, either (1) the number of solve variables must be three (as suggested by Daniel) or (2) the number of solve variables plus the number of elimination variables must be three. Eliminating either a, b, or c

```
Assuming[{a > b > 0, a > c > 0},
   Solve[{x0^2/a^2 + y0^2/b^2 == 1, 
      a^2 == b^2 + c^2, {x0 - c, y0} . {x0 + c, y0} == 0}, {x0, y0}, {#}, 
     Reals] // FullSimplify] & /@ {a, b, c}
```

[image]

Comment: Or you could use the option [`MaxExtraConditions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxExtraConditions.html)